# OpenJpa and JNDI

Tags: jpa, jndi, openjpa

For OpenJPA, how can I specify a JNDI connection in jta_datasource without specifying username and password in persistence.xml? It gives me an error when no username and password is specified in persistence.xml file for jndi.

Answer (score 1):

Great question; this isn't covered well in the OpenJPA documentation. What you need to do is use the special "java:comp/env/..." syntax for the "openjpa.ConnectionFactoryName" property to ask OpenJPA to retrieve the connection parameters from JNDI. For example, your persistence.xml should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence>
  <persistence-unit name="openjpa">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>tutorial.Animal</class>
    <class>tutorial.Dog</class>
    <class>tutorial.Rabbit</class>
    <class>tutorial.Snake</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myjndi"/>
      <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This will request a jndi resource called "myjndi" from the container. If you're using Tomcat, you would have a context.xml that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/myjndi"
        auth="Container"
        scope="Shareable"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="10000"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        username="username"
        password="password"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        />
</Context>
```

Change the JNDI parameters above as required for your database.

Comment: Thanks Templar. Unfortunately this hasn't resolved the problem. I am using openjpa on ibm websphere, my jndiname is A/B. I am now using 

<properties>
      <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryName" value="java:comp/env/A/B"/>
</properties>


I get the following exception:

A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.

Comment: when I specify ConnectionDriverName property, then it throws exception for username and password

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `jta-data-source` element in your persistence.xml.

```
<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/FooBarDataSourceJNDI</jta-data-source>
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration via code worked for me:

```
Map<String, String> conf = new HashMap<>();
conf.put("javax.persistence.jtaDataSource", "java:comp/env/jdbc/myjndi");
return getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager(conf);
```

I think I'm not placing `persistence.xml` in the proper location, yet.

Comment: it was misspelled. Now this is working, too: `<properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myjndi"/> </properties>`